# Moving ImageViews on and off the screen

Tags: android

I'm making a game on Android. In this game you can play cards like normal physical playing cards.

I want to be able to move imageViews as described below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Firstly, I was trying to move ImageViews this way:

```
    final View myView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float down_x=0, down_y=0;
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was DOWN: " + Float.toString(event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X)));
                        down_x = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X);
                        down_y = event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_Y);
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE):
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was MOVE: " + Float.toString(event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X)));
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "down_x: " + Float.toString(down_x) + "new Axis_X: " + Float.toString(event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X)));
                        if (down_x<event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X)) {
                            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "working");
                            myView.setLeft(myView.getLeft()+(int)(event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X)-down_x));
                        }

                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was UP: " + Float.toString(event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X)));
                        //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, Float.toString(event.getAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_X)));


           return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL):
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was CANCEL");
                        return true;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE):
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds " +
                                "of current screen element");
                        return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

However, it wasn't working as intended.

What tools should I use?

Comment: It could help if you post pictures of after in addition to the existing pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use event.getY() and event.getX() instead of event.getAxisValue() to get the position of the user's finger in pixels. If it doesn't matter whether the movement of the card should be executed as an atomic action (once the gesture to move the card to some direction is triggered, the card moves in that direction until some destined position without any more intervention from the user), you can use animations.

To use an animation, first define it in the anim folder inside your res directory:
Inside res/anim/anim_name.xml:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="200"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true"  <!-- Use fillEnabled and fillAfter to cause your view to remain in the position where it got to at the end of the animation instead of jumping back to the position where it was before the animation started -->
    />
```

then load it in your Java code:

```
Animation yourAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim_name);
```

Then when a gesture is discovered, launch the animation:

```
view.startAnimation(yourAnim);
```

If you want to allow a drag-and-drop action for the user, instead of using onTouch, you may want to use Android's drag and drop framework with an OnDragListener. See:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Comment: I'm not sure if it's misunderstanding or not but please bear in mind that it's significant which card you chooses. For example, you can move ace to the left if you want, not only the king.

Comment: If the cards are different views, your onTouch method has a View parameter which points to the specific View that was touched. You can start the animation on whatever card the user touches. I think it's better to try to work with drag and drop in this case (see my edit above). Sorry if I misunderstood your meaning.